# precision between float and double in C

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I understand there are several topics same as mine, but I still don't really get it, so I'm expecting someone could explain this in a more simple but explicit way for me instead of pasting other topics' links, thanks.

Here's a sample code:

```
int a = 960;
int b = 16;

float c = a*0.001;  
float d = a*0.001 + b;
double e = a*0.001 + b;

printf("%f\n%f\n%lf", c, d, e);
```

which outputs:

```
0.960000
16.959999
16.960000
```

My two questions are:

1. Why does adding an integer to a float ends up as the second output, but changing float to double solves the problem as the third output?
2. Why does the third output have the same number of digits with the first and second output after the decimal point since it should be a more precise value?

Comment: 1. What is the problem and why do you think switching to double solves it? 2. Because it always prints the same number of decimal digits, regardless of what you think the precision of a given number should be.

Comment: Plwase don't dismiss existing answers, especially massively upvoted ones, wholesale. This act implies that you deserve better answers than most people, and frankly it isn't quite clear why. Instead, ask about specific things that are unclear or unsatisfactory in the answers you have tried to read.

Comment: Note that `"%f"` in printf expects a value of type `double` (which your values of type `float` are automatically converted to provided you added the proper `#include <stdio.h>`). `"%lf"` is the same as `"%f"` since, I believe, C99 (`"%lf"` was not specified before that). If you have values of type `long double` use `"%Lf"`

Comment: ...as distinct from the format specifiers used with `scanf`.

Comment: @n.m. sorry, I didn't mean to feel I deserve better answers than most people.

Comment: @pmg thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why they produce the same number of decimal places, is because `6` is the default value. You can change that as in the edited example below, where the syntax is `%.*f`. The `*` can be either a number as shown below, or in the second case, supplied as another argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 960;
    int b = 16;

    float c = a*0.001;  
    float d = a*0.001 + b;
    double e = a*0.001 + b;

    printf("%.9f\n", c);
    printf("%.*f\n", 9, d);
    printf("%.16f\n", e);
}
```

Program output:

```
0.959999979
16.959999084
16.9600000000000009
```

The extra decimal places now shows that none of the results is exact. One reason is because `0.001` cannot be exactly coded as a floating point value. There are other reasons too, which have been extensively covered.

One easy way to understand why, is that a `float` has about `2^32` different values that can be encoded, however there is an infinity of real numbers within the range of `float`, and only about `2^32` of them can be represented *exactly*. In the case of the fraction `1/1000`, in binary it is a recurring value (as is the fraction `1/3` in decimal).

Comment: so "One reason is because 0.001 cannot be exactly coded as a floating point value."  also means @phuclv's "0.001 is a double literal, so the operation is always done in double precision" ?

Comment: The value `0.001` is of type `double`. The `a*0.001` multiplies that `double` by `960`, and then `float c = a*0.001;` reduces that `double` product to a `float` value.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the calculation a*0.001 will be done in double precision in both cases, then some precision is lost when you store it as a float.
2. You can choose how many decimal digits are printed by printf by writing e.g. "%.10lf" (to get 10 digits) instead of just "%lf".

Comment: `0.001` is a double literal, so the operation is always done in double precision

Comment: Note that although `%lf` is valid for `scanf`, it is unnecessary and non-conforming for `printf`.  Nevertheless, it is a widely-accepted extension.  This is relevant because it meshes closely with the fact that `float` arguments to `printf` are converted to `double` at the point of the call, so what the OP is observing is strictly the result of converting from `double` to `float` and back to `double`.

Comment: @Elias Thanks for the clear and simple answer! I accepted Weather Vane's answer because he has a more detailed answer. Though I wanted to mark your answer is useful, but my reputation is lower than 15..... sorry

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for pointing that out, but can I ask what is "OP" ?

Comment: @ØøØø about OP, see https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html : "OP is short for original poster -- the person who started a discussion thread." So in this case, you are the OP.

Comment: @Elias  haha, got it!